# O que é Trunk Based Development?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, versionamento

Recentemente fui apresentado a um artigo no Medium sobre Trunk Based Development (TBD). O título era totalmente provocativo, [You don't need Feature Branches anymore…](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/why-are-so-many-people-against-trunk-based-development-a785d9322584) ("Você não precisa mais de *Feature Branches*" em tradução livre).

Então, venho a questionar:

- O que é o TBD?
- Quais as promessas de resolução de problemas que o TBD promete resolver?
- Já usou na prática? Se sim, quais das vantagens *reais* que se obteve usando-o?

  - Aproveitando, quais as desvantagens que você vivenciou usando-o?
    Tanto em comparação com outro *code-flow* ou coisas que simplesmente você mesmo percebeu
- Como trabalhar com equipes remotas com TBD?
  Um dos pontos do artigo do Medium era que "Pair Programming é essencial", como fazer com uma equipe descentralizada? Ou com membros remotos sem proximidade física dos demais?

Comment: Alguém votou negativo sem ser seguido por um voto de fechamento. Gostaria de saber se tem algo que não mostrou nenhum esforço, ou falta de clareza/utilidade para a comunidade. Se tiver algo assim, por favor comente para que eu possa melhorar a pergunta

Comment: Fui quem dei downvote. Me desculpe n ter dado o motivo na hora, mas enfim, sua questão está absurdamente ampla, com pelo menos 4 perguntas. Em momento algum você é objetivo na dúvida, dizendo qual é o problema/dúvida específico que você tem e como/se você tentou resolver. No fim das contas, é impraticável responder tudo. Sugiro você ler melhor sobre o assunto (https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) e caso tenha alguma duvida PONTUAL, retornar ao SO para podermos ser mais objetivos na resolução.

Comment: @regmoraes, então foi falta de objetividade na dúvida e uma pergunta ampla de minha parte. Sua sugestão de melhoria seria dividi-la em perguntas menores de menor escopo e mais tratáveis, correto?

Comment: Exato. Com perguntas menores e mais objetivas é mais fácil de chegarmos numa resposta rápida. Com muitas perguntas numa mesma questão, fica trabalhoso e cansativo, o que pode inclusive espantar pessoas que até tenham algo pra contribuir, mas que por preguiça desistem (eu estou incluso hehe).

Comment: @regmoraes , o segundo ponto (promessas de resolução) é extremamente ligado ao ponto do que **é** o TBD. Afinal, por que falar dele sem falar do "porquê" usar o TBD? O terceiro ponto (e seu subponto) acaba sendo uma pergunta de uso prático, pedindo para relatar experiências. Parece-me algo integrado, ou tem discordância? Já o quarto ponto, equipe remota + TBD, parece um tanto deslocado na hora da releitura, meses após a escrita da pergunta. Mas, pelo menos eu tento justificar a presença dele ali. Talvez pudesse remover, quem sabe.

Comment: @regmoraes , e para terminar, ficaria extremamente lisongeado se você criasse um par de pergunta-resposta e marcasse essa como duplicata da sua pergunta. Assim, posso criar uma nova pergunta (e deixar essa ser marcada como duplicata) focando no que faltou (ou novas perguntas no plural, se eu perceber que alguns temas que acho justo não entraram adequadamente na resposta da eventual hipotética pergunta-resposta que você vier a fazer